# Prepared PDO query returns 0 affected rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepare

I've literally spent hours Googling and searching and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm using POST, and I tried the query myself in phpMyAdmin, and it worked, but it's not working in PDO, and I don't know why. It worked when I used mysql_query and what not, but I want to protect myself from SQL injection.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['user']) and isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $name = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****;charset=utf8', '*****', '*****');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM stored WHERE _User LIKE :username AND _Pass LIKE :password");
        $query->bindValue(":username", $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(":password", $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $query->execute();

        echo $query->rowCount();
    }
?>
```

Comment: `For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Please, copy the code in. Make it easier for folks to help you :)

Comment: Aside from all other questions, **where on the Earth did you get that idea of using LIKE for string comparison?**

Comment: @Akam It does return the number of rows affected, as I have modified the statement before and it returned the number I expected. I can't even post the code because this site's formatting is bad and screws it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're naming the username variable $name in row 41, but when you bind the parameter on row 46, you call it $user.

Comment: Well, I'm retarded. That was it, you're a genius. I guess I should pay more attention to keeping consistency. Thanks a lot for ending my many hours of arduous searching for something that was my fault. I'm finally able to go to sleep. Thanks again.

Comment: @TidasBay a simple `error_reporting(E_ALL);` can save you all these hours.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are using ancient version of PHP, or there are no rows in your database matching the criteria. Upgrade for the first and check your data and query for the second.

Also, as Holy Linus spake to us, "Talk Is Cheap, Show Me The Code".
Don't tell us "It worked when I used blah blah query". **Run it.** In the very same file, next to very this code. This way you will have a **proof.** Only such a proof matters, while your speculations aren't.

However, strictly speaking, you don't need this function at all, as well as most of your code

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM stored WHERE _User = ? AND _Pass = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']));
echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

is enough.

Comment: How would I upgrade? Contact my web host? I have already tested the query and it has worked in phpMyAdmin. http://i.imgur.com/iUqUrMW.png

Comment: before upgrade you need to know if there is a problem. ALL your actions are based on a mere assumptions. Why not to make yourself understand the problem and only then start for the solution?

Comment: Anyway, it turned out to be a silly typo, caused by lack of error reporting